# Add comment - two model in one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to add two model in one view: CommentVM and BlogVM.
CommentVM - comments,
BlogVM - postDetails.
I try to  add comment via ajax to my databse and than pass my two model in to view. But when I try to display my page I received error that my object is null (commentVM)
below code my controller
Any sugestion what I am doing wrong?
Thank for your help!

```
// GET: Admin/Blog/kategoria/{name}/post/id
    [ActionName("post")]
    public ActionResult PostDetails(int id)
    {
        //Declare BlogVM
           BlogVM model;
        CommentVM model2;

        int id2;

             using (Db db = new Db())
             {
                 //Get the page
                 BlogDTO dto = db.Blog.Find(id);


                 //Confirm page exist
                 if (dto == null)
                 {
                     return Content("Taka strona nie istnieje!");
                 }

                 //Init BlogVM
                model = new BlogVM(dto);

            id2 = dto.Id;
           // CommentDTO dto2 = db.Comments.Find(x => x.PostId == id2);

            model2 = new CommentVM();
        }

            var finalItem = new DetailsComment
            {
                Blog = model,
                Comment = model2
            };

        return View("PostDetails", finalItem);

    }
```

code my models:

```
public class CommentVM
{
    public CommentVM()
    {

    }

    public CommentVM(CommentDTO row)
    {
        Id = row.Id;
        Name = row.Name;
        Body = row.Body;
        PostId = row.PostId;
        CreatedAt = row.CreatedAt;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    //public IEnumerable<CommentVM> CommentDetails { get; set; }
}



public class BlogVM
{
    public BlogVM()
    {

    }

    public BlogVM(BlogDTO row)
    {
        Id = row.Id;
        Title = row.Title;
        Slug = row.Slug;
        Body = row.Body;
        CategoryName = row.CategoryName;
        CategoryId = row.CategoryId;
        CreatedAt = row.CreatedAt;
        Sorting = row.Sorting;
        HasSidebar = row.HasSidebar;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(int.MaxValue, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public int Sorting { get; set; }
    public bool HasSidebar { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
}





public class DetailsComment
{
    public BlogVM Blog { get; set; }
    public CommentVM Comment { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CommentVM> CommentDetails { get; set; }
}
```

In my view

```
@foreach (var item in Model.CommentDetails)
                {

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="ajaxdivtd"></div>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Body)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedAt)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

Comment: Your `finalItem` variable only sets values for `Blog` and `Comment`, not for `CommentDetails`.

Comment: Why do you have a CommentVM object and a CommentVM list inside of DetailsComment class? From what I understood, you'll have a lot of comments for a specific post, is that right?

Comment: Yes, I have many comments to one post

Comment: I try to do that but i received error    ->  @foreach (var item in Model.Comment)   -> ERROR: foreach statement cannot operate on variable of type CommentVm because CommentVM does'nt not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator.  Any sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

If, according to your comments, you have multiple comments per post, then here's what you need to do:

```
//Declare BlogVM
BlogVM model;
CommentVM model2; //you can probably get rid of this variable since you want multiple comments per post, rather than a single one, but that's up to you
List<CommentVM> commentsModel; //new List object to hold the multiple comments for the post
```

and:

```
id2 = dto.Id;
var dto2 = db.Comments.Find(x => x.PostId == id2);
//Convert dto2 from an list/enumerable of CommentDTO to a List<CommentVM>, perhaps via AutoMapper (or other such utility), or even manually via a foreach
commentsModel = YourConversionMethod(dto2);
```

finally:

```
var finalItem = new DetailsComment
{
    Blog = model,
    Comment = model2,
    CommentDetails = commentsModel
};
```

Comment: var dto2 = db.Comments.Find(x => x.PostId == id2);    it this line I get ERROR: cannot convert lambda expression to type object because it is not a delegate type

Comment: OK, then perhaps your `Find` method only allows objects, and is the incorrect method to use to retrieve multiple records. Without knowing more about your setup, it's difficult to say what the appropriate method is to perform this function. In our setup, we have an `IQueryable<TEntity>` object that allows us to use `.Where` with filters such as  `x => x.PostId == id2`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tred this but it didn't work. Maybe because I am new in ASP. I only want in my aplication pass two model in my view: one with post details(BlogVM it works) and second with comment details(CommentVM it doesn't work). If you have any suggestion or example, please let me know.

Comment: You're already doing that by passing one model (`DetailsComment`) that contains your child models (`Blog` and `Comment`/`CommentDetails`). Your problem isn't with passing multiple models, but with retrieving the data to populate the `CommentDetails` model. In my solution, if you change `CommentDetails = commentsModel` to `CommentDetails = new List<CommentVM>()`, it should allow your View to load without error, albeit without any actual comments to iterate and display.